# Is it possible to use a custom-defined decision tree classifier in Scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a predefined decision tree, which I built from knowledge-based splits, that I want to use to make predictions. I could try to implement a decision tree classifier from scratch, but then I would not be able to use build in Scikit functions like predict. Is there a way to convert my tree in pmml and import this pmml to make my prediction with scikit-learn? Or do I need to do something completely different?
My first attempt was to use “fake training data” to force the algorithm to build the tree the way I like it, this would end up in a lot of work because I need to create different trees depending on the user input.

Comment: can you add some sample code? when and were do you get the error?

Comment: please consult this page and reformat your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PalimPalim I don't have any code to show. My question is how can I create my own classifier and still be able to use scikit-learn functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own decision tree classifier using Sklearn API. Please [read this documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#developing-scikit-learn-estimators) following the predictor class types. As explained in [this section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#rolling-your-own-estimator), you can build an estimator following the template:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_array, check_is_fitted
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances

class TemplateClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, demo_param='demo'):
        self.demo_param = demo_param

    def fit(self, X, y):
        # Two paths. Just return the object, or implement here your decision rules
        return self

    def predict(self, X):

        # Check is fit had been called
        check_is_fitted(self)

        # Input validation
        X = check_array(X)

        # Change this to your decision tree "rules"
        closest = np.argmin(euclidean_distances(X, self.X_), axis=1)
        return self.y_[closest]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I will stick with this solution. Actually I was hoping it would be possible to build my classifier with the tree class from Scikit-Learn.

Comment: @eva you can develop your classifier following the code of scikit learn DecisionTreeClassifier, here you have the link of the class, maybe it can help you: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L585