# Create a decision tree with a custom node logic

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to estimate a human level performance of a certain classification task.

Let's say I have the following fixed logic:

```
def classify(feature_1, feature_2):

    if feature_1 <= threshold_1:
        return 0

    if feature_2 <= threshold_2:
        return 1

    return 2
```

How can I import or rewrite this logic to form a fully eligible [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) with attributes (`classes_`, `n_classes_`, `tree_`, ect.), methods (`fit`, `decision_path`, `set_params`, ect.) and [`sklearn.tree.export_text`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html#sklearn.tree.export_text) possibility?

```
|--- feature_1 <= threshold_1
|   |--- class: 0
|--- feature_1 >  threshold_1
|   |--- feature_2 <= threshold_2
|   |   |--- class: 1
|   |--- feature_2 > threshold_2
|   |   |--- class: 2
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935395/is-it-possible-to-use-a-custom-defined-decision-tree-classifier-in-scikit-learn) suggest to build a custom ([BaseEstimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html#sklearn-base-baseestimator), [ClassifierMixin](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin.html#sklearn-base-classifiermixin)) but not the [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you give a decision tree model some data which has features and target predictions. The model determines the thresholds (as well as the tree structure) that minimize the prediction error with respect to the data. Then you can retrieve the resulting tree structure and thresholds from the model so you can analyze them and better explain why your model makes the predictions it does.

But you can also construct a custom model as the link suggested. Just don't try to go through the `DecisionTreeClassifier` class. That is based on a builder pattern where the builder is the training process. There is no way to specify the tree to that class directly. Also, you don't get any advantages of using `DecisionTreeClassifier` over a custom estimator given that the custom estimator, if built right, can interact with the rest of the sklearn tools just as well as `DecisionTreeClassifier`.